# Change Task Manger title for win32 console app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, vcxproj

I am trying to change the name of my win32 console application in task manager. In c# console project I can set the `AssemblyTitle` in project file and it would work but for some reason when I can't achieve the same result here.

Comment: [`SetConsoleTitle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle)?

Comment: Would that work if I convert the console to a background app??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right-click the Resource file to add a `.rc` file.

[image]

Then double-click the `.rc` file to enter the resource view, right-click the resource file and select `Add Resource`, and select `Version`.

[image]

In the `VS_VERSION_INFO`, you can modify the `FileDescription` to your application name (of course you can also modify other application information.).

[image]

Finally build the project and this works for me.

[image]

Comment: This describes exactly what I was looking for, thanks.